# /0123456789.html get Number with regex

Tags: regex, url, numbers

I really don't get it, probably I will never understand regex. Sorry!

If I have a string like

```
/0123456789.html
```

I want to excerpt the number. The length has 8-10 digits. With

```
\/[0-9]{8,10}(?:.html)
```

I get the whole part, but I just want the period of numbers (here 0123456789).

Comment: What you are missing is a capture group. if you surround `[0-9]{8,10}` with parentheses you'll capture the numbers in the first capture group https://regex101.com/r/U26eNC/1

Comment: Please specify language/technology you're using in tags

Comment: I'm using PHP. Zenoo's reply was the solution.Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=\/)\d{8,10}(?=\.html)`](https://regex101.com/r/qmAHPp/1)

- `(?<=\/)` makes sure there is a `/` before your match
- `\d{8,10}` matches a digit between 8 and 10 times
- `(?=\.html)` makes sure your match is followed by `.html`

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/qmAHPp/1)

Comment: Thx a lot, that's it! :-) I'm glad you could help me.